# Adding values in ManyToManyField through the Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

I'm a newbie in Django, so can you help me to understand how the save() method works?

Here's my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Tag', max_length=200, unique=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Entry title', max_length=200)
    # some more fields here
    tags_string = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Tags', max_length=200, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

There is `tags_string` where user enters tags separated by comma. It's just a string.

Then I'm trying to add tags to ManyToManyField by clicking "Save" in Django admin:

```
def save(self):
    super(Entry, self).save()
    if self.tags_string:
        for tag in tags_string.split(","):
            t = Tag.objects.create(name=tag)
            self.tags.add(t)
```

but it doesn't work. `entry.tags.add(t)` works perfectly through the Django shell - it adds the values to the database. I think that something is wrong in my save() method.

Could you suggest me how to fix it, please?

Comment: where are you filling `self.tags_string`?

Comment: In django admin. it's just a CharField which parsed later in save() method.

Comment: I would try `print self.tags_string` .. maybe there's the problem. Everything else seems correct

Comment: print self.tags_string returns the string. it's ok. also, tags are succesfully created here: t = Tag.objects.create(name=tag) and saved in database. but relation table entry_tags is empty.

Comment: I've seen weird behaviour with m2m fields in django sometimes... does it behave differently at all if you switch to a different database (eg sqlite?)?  Or, can you make a minimal repro, with no other code?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def save(self):
    super(Entry, self).save()
    if self.tags_string:
        for tag in tags_string.split(","):
            self.tags.create(name=tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the M2M tags format and print those?

```
def save(self):
   super(Entry, self).save()
   if self.tags_string:
       print self.tags,type(self.tags)   
       for tag in tags_string.split(","):
          .......
```

Comment: print self.tags,type(self.tags) returns this: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x9c905ac> <class 'django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager'>

Answer (score 0):

First, `save` has additional parameters that you need to account for. Second, you should be using `get_or_create` instead of `create` for the tags:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.tags_string:
        for tag in tags_string.split(","):
            t, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
            self.tags.add(t)
```

Those may not fix the current issue, but it would have got you eventually.

You should also probably be doing some sort of normalization on the tags as well, using `str.lower()` or `title()` from `django.template.defaultfilters`. Otherwise, you'll end up with "Tag", "tag", "TAG" and "tAg".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris. It still doesn't work, but looks much better :)